# Move x element to the end of an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, arel

I'm trying to find a method to take a particular relation and move it to the end of the array. Basically, I have a `current_account` and I want to take this account and move it to the end of the account relationship array so that it will display last when I iteration over the relationships. I want to make a scope and use SQL if possible, here is my attempt and I haven't really gotten anywhere.

HTML

```
<% current_user.accounts.current_sort(current_account).each do |account| %>
   <li><%= link_to account.name, switch_account_accounts_path(account_id: account.id) %></li>
<% end %>
```

This current return a list of sorted by created_at accounts. I don't want it to be sorted by created at but the `current_account` to be at the bottom so I make a scope called `current_sort` but I'm not sure what to do here.

CURRENT_SORT SCOPE ON ACCOUNT

```
 scope :current_sort, lambda { |account|

 }
```

I want this scope to return the passed in account last in the association array. How can I do this with SQL or Ruby?

Comment: Why not just `sort_by { |v| v == current_account ? 1 : 0 }`?

Comment: @tadman That works great! No reason not to.

Comment: You can also do `list - [ current_account ] + [ current_account ]` but that seems more messy.

Comment: Yea, That's an interesting take though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A quick trick to sort a particular element to the end of an array is:

```
array.sort_by { |v| v == current_account ? 1 : 0 }
```

If you want to move multiple elements it's easier to do:

```
to_end = [ a, b ]

array - to_end + to_end
```

**Edit:** As Stefan points out, this could potentially re-order items. To fix that:

```
array.sort_by.with_index do |v, i|
  v == current_account ? (array.length + i) : i
end
```

You can also approach it a different way using [`partition`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition):

```
array.partition { |v| v != current_account }.reduce(:+)
```

Which is a variation on the method used by Stefan in their answer.

Comment: That is great. Note that `array - to_end + to_end` only works in a set like manner. `[1,1,1,1,1,2]-[1]==[2]`

Comment: Ruby's `sort` / `sort_by` is not stable. Your solution puts `current_account` at the end, but it can inadvertently reorder the remaining items. This can be fixed by taking each item's index into account, i.e.: `array.sort_by.with_index { |v, i | [v == current_account ? 1 : 0, i] }`

Comment: @Stefan That's a good point. I've added two other methods to account for that, one of which apparently you've already mentioned now that I've checked.

Comment: Why do you have `(array.length + i) : i` and not just `1 : 0`? Seems redundant given the following `, i` but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Stefan Ah, I see what you mean with using a secondary sort factor in that array.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`partition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) to split the array by a condition.

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
current_account = 3

other_accounts, current_accounts = array.partition { |v| v != current_account }
#=> [[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [3]]

other_accounts
#=> [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

current_accounts
#=> [3]
```

The results can be concatenated:

```
other_accounts + current_accounts
#=> [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 3]
```

or in a single line:

```
array.partition { |v| v != current_account }.flatten(1)
#=> [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 3]

# or

array.partition { |v| v != current_account }.inject(:+)
#=> [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 3]
```